# Alternative to battery powered isolated voltage source

Tags: power-supply, voltage-source

For some nano-physics related measurements, a very clean low-noise bias current is required. People mostly use a battery powered isolated voltage source along with a big resistance similar to [this](https://www.thinksrs.com/products/sim928.html).

1. Is there anyway, alternatively I can have a clean source using a regular voltage source, let's say a Keithley DC power supply, and an off-the shelf filter to clean it up?
2. Any recommendation for the filter?

Appreciate your responses.

*Added notes:*

I would like the noise to be in the order of 10 μVrms (1kHz bandwidth), similar to the device above.
By recommendation: I mean what to search for. Is there any technical term for these types of filters.

Comment: For the kind of noise control that you're talking about, you're not going to get an answer from the internet. You're going to have to try some experiments and see what works in your environment (interference sources) and for your application (how low does the noise need to be? In what frequency bands? etc)

Comment: An interesting question, but recommendations for things to buy are off topic here.

Comment: You should say how long the voltage source needs to operate, what the bias current range is (should I assume you mean a current source from the context I'm reading -- sounds like it -- but you should say if that's so), what noise specs you have for "low-noise" and "clean." Etc. You can make a very "clean" voltage reference in a chem lab. But it works well only for so long of a time.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers: @ThePhoton in the order of 10 μVrms (1kHz bandwidth).  .

Comment: Thank you @JRE:  I mean what to search for. Is there any technical term for these types of filters

Comment: Thank you @jonk The current is in the order of 10uA but the impedance swings widely. So, a large resistor of tens of KOhms is used to get current from a voltage source.  And the noise is good to be int he order of  in the order of 10 μVrms (1kHz bandwidth).